# Picture not showing up right

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a gallery where different pictures are to be shown.
i wanted to do the effect that, when i click on the image it gets bigger and it stays that big as long as i click it.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI4TP.jpg)

but when i click on it, it zooms in but the image gets cut off
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zPT9.jpg)

i used a list for the gallery and added some css to it.

the code for the image zoom is this:

```
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to set a z-index to it, if you want it to pop out on top of the other images, if that's what the question is about, or make the photo fit in that window to 100% rather than a fixed pixel width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably is a `z-index` issue. I am guessing that the image you click is relatively positioned (and if it isn't, you should do it). Then, simply set the `z-index` to a higher number and you should be fine!

Example:
`z-index: 100;`